# How to track the caller details inside callee in python

Tags: python

I am calling the function which sits in module(module2.py)  from the another class which sits in the module called module1.py

for example:

```
*module2.py*

def test_envconfig():
     #I have to get the name/parent base class details of caller to this function
     #print the caller function name is ?
     #print the location of the caller function is ?
     return "user"

*module1.py*

class MyClass(SomeOther):
    def process(self):
         module2.test_envconfig()
```

In the above example the process method inside **MyClass** calls to the **test_envconfig** function in **module1**.So, I have to fetch the details about the caller (here **MyClass** -> baseclass **SomeOther**) inside **test_envconfig** function (including the base class hierarchy details)

So, How can i get the details of the caller function(MyClass-->SomeOther) inside the callee(test_envconfig)?

**Edit:** Reason for doing this:*

Dynamically, The architecture was designed for the situation for sharing with multiple projects.We have the plenty of modules calls to the function `test_envconfig` to active the environment.For few modules from the particular location should be activated to the environment (user) when it calls to `test_envconfig`, other few modules from some other location should be activated for the environment 'prod' when it calls the same `test_envconfig`. Based on the location of the modules the environment activation happens. The `test_envconfig` is responsible for activating the environment with necessary configurations.

Could you please help to findout the caller location and name details inside `test_envconfig`?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? The easiest approach would be to make it explicit - add an `obj` parameter to `test_envconfig` and then call `module2.test_envconfig(self)` in `MyClass`.

Comment: It is the dynamic operation, there are plenty module calls to the `test_envconfig`. for few modules i have to redirect to another caller.So, I have to fetch the caller details at runtime inside `test_envconfig`

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context? What is the function **for**? In general, you can use [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) for introspection, but there may be easier ways to approach this.

Comment: added few more description

Comment: A much easier, more intuitive, and more configurable solution would be to pass in the environment type to `test_envconfig`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo yeah that's right. The problem is the caller modules are already in setup.So, things has to happen without disturbing the callers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got answer after a couple of try.

The solution which works for me.Your suggestions are welcome.

module2.py

```
def test_envconfig():
     import inspect
     for frame, filename, line_num, func, source_code, source_index in inspect.stack():
         if 'tests/unittests/capital/' in filename:
             print 'The Test env is activated for %s' % (filename)
     return "user"
```